# Windows 7 CreateProcess, child process cannot write file?

Tags: windows, createprocess

I'm confused. I have program which I run as a non-administrator user. This program can write files in my C:\Program Files\ folder.

However, if I launch a second program using CreateProcess from within the first program, the second program cannot write to the C:\Program Files\ folder.

What are the correct parameters to pass into CreateProcess() to use the same access privileges as the first launching program? I've tried setting the 3rd and 4th parameters as NULL but that didn't seem to work.

```
BOOL RunCmd( char  *pCmd, 
             char  *pParams, 
             char  *pWorkingDir, 
             int    nWaitSecs, 
             BOOL   fQuietMode, 
             DWORD *pdwExitCode )
{
  BOOL                fSuccess = TRUE;
  STARTUPINFO         si;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

  ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
  ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

  si.cb          = sizeof( si );
  si.dwFlags     = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  si.wShowWindow = ( fQuietMode ) ? SW_HIDE : SW_SHOW;

  // PDS: This is the important stuff - file handle needs to be inheritable..
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sFileSecurity;
  ZeroMemory( &sFileSecurity, sizeof( sFileSecurity ) );
  sFileSecurity.nLength        = sizeof( sFileSecurity );
  sFileSecurity.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

  char txCmdLine[ MAX_PATH * 2 ];

  strcpy( txCmdLine, "\"" );
  strcat( txCmdLine, pCmd );
  strcat( txCmdLine, "\"" );

  if( pParams )
  {
    // PDS: Add any parameters if we have them..
    strcat( txCmdLine, " " );
    strcat( txCmdLine, pParams );
  }

  int rc;

  // Start the child process. 

      rc = CreateProcess( NULL, // No module name (use command line). 
                          txCmdLine, // Command line. 
                          &sFileSecurity,             // Process handle not inheritable. 
                          &sFileSecurity,             // Thread handle not inheritable. 

                          FALSE,

                          // PDS: Don't pop up window for application.. quiet mode!
                          CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
                          NULL,             // Use parent's environment block. 
                          pWorkingDir,      // Working folder
                          &si,              // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
                          &pi );            // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - the primary program couldn't create the file either. The issue was confused by the fact that the primary program was being launched from an installation program that was run as an administrator. The system then rebooted and the primary program was auto-started with the current user's access privilege.. who didn't have access to the  folder.

Answer (score 1):

Is the application that you are launching 64 bit?  For 32 processes Windows will [re-direct writes to Program Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756960.aspx) to `%localappdata%\VirtualStore` so they succeed but it won't do the same for 64 bit processes.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Its a 32bit process running on a 32bit laptop. I did have the issue of it trying to create a file in VirtualStore. After recompiling the secondary program with VS2010 I confirmed with ProcMon.exe that the CreateFile() call is definitely taking place in C:\Program Files\<MyApp> now. This is what shows the result "ACCESS DENIED". So.. both programs are built with the same VS2010, both written by myself with the same style of code.. both are 32bit.. so all I can think of is that its a problem with inheriting insufficient security access credentials from the parent program.